# socket connection error in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, minecraft

I programmed a website for minecraft servers and I have a problem.
my website is:
[Serv-Craft](http://serv-craft.com)

My host is iPage and on the servers section I check if the server is offline or online.
The problem is that all of the servers that I check are online and the website output that 
they are online.
I tried to put my website on another host and my code worked
The other site: [Serv-Craft Temp Host](http://servcraft.000space.com)

What to do??
My code is:

```
<?php

function GetServerStatus($site, $port)
{
    $status = array("<img src='images/icons/off.png' title='Offline'><br>Offline", "<img       src='images/icons/online.png' title='Online!'><br>Online");
    $fp = fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.35);

    if (!$fp) {
        return $status[0];
    } else { 
        return $status[1];
    }
}

print_r(GetServerStatus($server_ip, $server_port)); 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) if [allow url fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is activated.

Comment: my host is compitable with fsockopen

Comment: What is within the "$site, $port" parameter? Please place an error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);  above all.